# Single Selection RecyclerView TextView

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, textview, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that displays items from `Firestore`.

What I've done and it's working is that when an item is clicked, it will be added to firestore and its background will change color to red.

But what I want is that when another text is clicked, that item should be deselected and its background returned to default. What happens is that the item is only removed from firestore. Only **ONE** item must be selected and added to firestore.

I searched all what I've found on stackoverflow and I didn't found what I wanted.

This is my code:

```
holder.sizeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                firebaseFirestore.collection("Shopping Cart").document(userID).collection("Products").document(productID).collection("Size").document("Product Size").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();

                            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                                firebaseFirestore.collection("Shopping Cart").document(userID).collection("Products").document(productID).collection("Size").document("Product Size").delete();

                                holder.sizeView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.size_text_background);

                                Toast.makeText(context, "Size Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else {

                                Map<String, String> productSizeMap = new HashMap<>();
                                productSizeMap.put("size", sizeID);

                                firebaseFirestore.collection("Shopping Cart").document(userID).collection("Products").document(productID).collection("Size").document("Product Size").set(productSizeMap);

                                holder.sizeView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.size_text_background_clicked);

                                Toast.makeText(context, "Size Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

Any help please? If there is some other code that you want to see I will post it. And thanks in advance.

*SMALL EDIT:*

How can I make it a required field so that the Add To Cart button can be clickble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show you how to achieve what you are looking for using a simple example to show a list of strings.

My view to represent a item in RecyclerView view will be `test_cell_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/holder_background"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I created an adapter extending `RecyclerView.Adapter`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private int selectedPos = 0;

    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View viewItem, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout background;
        TextView itemText;

        ViewHolder(final View viewItem) {
            super(viewItem);
            background = (LinearLayout) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.holder_background);
            itemText = (TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.item_text);

            viewItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Triggers click upwards to the adapter on click
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(viewItem, position);
                            notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);
                            selectedPos =getAdapterPosition();
                            notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        public void changeToSelect(int colorBackground) {
            background.setBackgroundColor(colorBackground);
        }
    }

    private List<String> list;
    private Context context;

    public TestAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context= context;
    }

    @Override
    public TestAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_cell_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder itemViewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        return itemViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.changeToSelect(selectedPos == position ? Color.parseColor("#ca3854") : Color.BLACK);
        TextView filterText = holder.itemText;
        filterText.setTextSize(30);
        filterText.setText(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

Here you can see that i have created a Interface to use as the OnItemClickListener. I have defined a global variable to hold the currently selected item position. When everytime a view is clicked i change the selected item position and notifychanges to the adapter so that it can update its view with changes. OnBindViewHolder method i change the color of the background to select color if the position is currently selected position and to black if not.

In activity i used adapter like this,

```
        RecyclerView view = findViewById(R.id.view);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 100; i < 150; i++) {
            list.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }
        TestAdapter adaptor = new TestAdapter(this, list);
        adaptor.setOnItemClickListener(new TestAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View viewItem, int position) {
                //Your item click code
            }
        });
        view.setAdapter(adaptor);
        LinearLayoutManager liveImageLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        liveImageLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        view.setLayoutManager(liveImageLayoutManager);
```

I hope you can take a look at this and adapt how it is done to your code.

Comment: Okay first thanks for your answer. Second, your code is working pretty fine. But when I adapted it to my code, it becomes weird. For example, when I click on an item, its color becomes the one in the code. When I click on another item, the color popups and the item become selected on the second click. One more thing, I have 2 differents drawable files for the state of the selection: one has a black border and the other one has a red one. How can I set the drawable according to the selection instead of changing the background color? And how to deselect the item when clicking again on it?

Comment: I'll check on this and post a suggestion.

Comment: So..have you anything new?

Comment: Did you remove holder.sizeView.setOnclickListener your previous implementation? if not remove it and put all your firebase methods in onItemClickListener that i have created. That might be the problem